# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. How do I remove

Tags: vb.net

I have a userform embedded in a form, form2, and for some reason I started getting the following. 
"object reference not set to instance of an object"  Only in design mode on the form2.

If i 'ignore and continue' through, and run the project the form works fine without issue, and the error message persists.

click here to see screen shot of error.
[form2 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxoWO.png)

Here is [form2.designer.vb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3iEy.gif)

The code form the userform load event is below and I've copied the line that's triggering the error above that.  If I comment out the line the design error goes away.

```
If CType(Me.ParentForm.Owner, Form1).DataGridView1.Columns(col).ReadOnly = False Then 



Public Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim DS As New PIMUserDBDataSet.ewosappendixDataTable
    Dim col As Integer


    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()

    With DS
        For col = 0 To .Columns.Count - 1
            If CType(Me.ParentForm.Owner, Form1).DataGridView1.Columns(col).ReadOnly = False Then                    ComboBox1.Items.Add(DS.Columns(col).ColumnName)
            End If
        Next
        ComboBox1.Sorted = True
    End With


End Sub
```

Any advice on how to resolve this is much appreciated.

thanks,

here's the event code that loads/shows form 2 as it will help you identify the parent of form2/usercontrol1.

```
 Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ufm As New Form2
    ufm.Owner = Me


    ufm.Show()


End Sub
```

**Here is my form1.vb.design**

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
```

Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

```
'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
    Me.DataGridView1 = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView()
    Me.EwosappendixbindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components)
    Me.PIMUserDBDataSet = New WindowsApplication6.PIMUserDBDataSet()
    Me.UserSearch = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.Timer1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer(Me.components)
    Me.ToolTipCustlb = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip(Me.components)
    Me.Label1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Label()
    Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
    Me.EWOSFormBindingSource = New System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(Me.components)
    Me.EWOS_FormTableAdapter = New WindowsApplication6.PIMUserDBDataSetTableAdapters.EWOS_FormTableAdapter()
    Me.EwosappendixTableAdapter = New WindowsApplication6.PIMUserDBDataSetTableAdapters.ewosappendixTableAdapter()
    Me.WorkerDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.ExecutiveDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.OwncodeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.MaxusecusnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.FinalownDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.PidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.ExecsummaryDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.Custliab1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.Reqvendreturn5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.Pimvendreturn6DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.Pmvendreturnesc7DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.AdddtDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.BpsverticalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.ProdmgrDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.VendNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.EWOSClassDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.VendPNDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.LongDescDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.QtyavailDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.ValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.TurnsDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.InventoryanalystDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.ExecReviewDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.SrnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    Me.SR120DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
    CType(Me.DataGridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    CType(Me.EwosappendixbindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    CType(Me.PIMUserDBDataSet, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    CType(Me.EWOSFormBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'DataGridView1
    '
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
    Me.DataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = True
    Me.DataGridView1.Anchor = CType((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) _
        Or System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right), System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)
    Me.DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    Me.DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize
    Me.DataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn() {Me.WorkerDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.ExecutiveDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.OwncodeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.MaxusecusnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.FinalownDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.PidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.ExecsummaryDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.Custliab1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.Reqvendreturn5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.Pimvendreturn6DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.Pmvendreturnesc7DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.AdddtDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.BpsverticalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.ProdmgrDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.VendNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.EWOSClassDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.VendPNDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.LongDescDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.QtyavailDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.ValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.TurnsDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.InventoryanalystDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.ExecReviewDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.SrnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, Me.SR120DataGridViewTextBoxColumn})
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.EwosappendixbindingSource
    Me.DataGridView1.EditMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
    Me.DataGridView1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(21, 34)
    Me.DataGridView1.Name = "DataGridView1"
    Me.DataGridView1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1287, 619)
    Me.DataGridView1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'EwosappendixbindingSource
    '
    Me.EwosappendixbindingSource.AllowNew = False
    Me.EwosappendixbindingSource.DataMember = "ewosappendix"
    Me.EwosappendixbindingSource.DataSource = Me.PIMUserDBDataSet
    '
    'PIMUserDBDataSet
    '
    Me.PIMUserDBDataSet.DataSetName = "PIMUserDBDataSet"
    Me.PIMUserDBDataSet.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema
    '
    'UserSearch
    '
    Me.UserSearch.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(720, 8)
    Me.UserSearch.Name = "UserSearch"
    Me.UserSearch.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(102, 20)
    Me.UserSearch.TabIndex = 1
    Me.UserSearch.Visible = False
    '
    'Timer1
    '
    Me.Timer1.Interval = 750
    '
    'Label1
    '
    Me.Label1.AutoSize = True
    Me.Label1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(18, 11)
    Me.Label1.Name = "Label1"
    Me.Label1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(38, 13)
    Me.Label1.TabIndex = 2
    Me.Label1.Text = "Filter : "
    '
    'Button1
    '
    Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(1153, 5)
    Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
    Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(102, 23)
    Me.Button1.TabIndex = 3
    Me.Button1.Text = "Mass Update"
    Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
    '
    'EWOSFormBindingSource
    '
    Me.EWOSFormBindingSource.AllowNew = False
    Me.EWOSFormBindingSource.DataMember = "EWOS_Form"
    Me.EWOSFormBindingSource.DataSource = Me.PIMUserDBDataSet
    '
    'EWOS_FormTableAdapter
    '
    Me.EWOS_FormTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = True
    '
    'EwosappendixTableAdapter
    '
    Me.EwosappendixTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = True
    '
    'WorkerDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    '
    Me.WorkerDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "worker"
    Me.WorkerDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "worker"
    Me.WorkerDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "WorkerDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"
    '
    'ExecutiveDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    '
    Me.ExecutiveDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "executive"
    Me.ExecutiveDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "executive"
    Me.ExecutiveDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "ExecutiveDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"
    '
    'OwncodeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    '
    Me.OwncodeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "owncode"
    Me.OwncodeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "owncode"
    Me.OwncodeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "OwncodeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"
    '
    'MaxusecusnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    '
    Me.MaxusecusnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "maxusecusno"
    Me.MaxusecusnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "maxusecusno"
    Me.MaxusecusnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "MaxusecusnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"
    Me.MaxusecusnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = True
    '
    'FinalownDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    '
    Me.FinalownDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "finalown"
    Me.FinalownDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "finalown"
    Me.FinalownDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "FinalownDataGridViewTextBoxColumn"
    '

    'SR120DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    '
    Me.SR120DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "SR120"
    Me.SR120DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "SR120"
    Me.SR120DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "SR120DataGridViewTextBoxColumn"
    Me.SR120DataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ReadOnly = True
    '
    'Form1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.AutoSize = True
    Me.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1362, 703)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.Label1)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.UserSearch)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.DataGridView1)
    Me.Name = "Form1"
    Me.Text = "EWOS"
    CType(Me.DataGridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    CType(Me.EwosappendixbindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    CType(Me.PIMUserDBDataSet, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    CType(Me.EWOSFormBindingSource, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub

Friend WithEvents DataGridView1 As DataGridView
Friend WithEvents PIMUserDBDataSet As PIMUserDBDataSet
Friend WithEvents EWOS_FormTableAdapter As PIMUserDBDataSetTableAdapters.EWOS_FormTableAdapter
Friend WithEvents UserSearch As TextBox
Friend WithEvents Timer1 As Timer
Friend WithEvents EWOSFormBindingSource As BindingSource
Friend WithEvents ToolTipCustlb As ToolTip
Friend WithEvents Label1 As Label
Friend WithEvents EwosappendixTableAdapter As PIMUserDBDataSetTableAdapters.ewosappendixTableAdapter
Friend WithEvents EwosappendixbindingSource As BindingSource
Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button
Friend WithEvents WorkerDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents ExecutiveDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents OwncodeDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents MaxusecusnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents FinalownDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents PidDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents ExecsummaryDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents Custliab1DataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents Reqvendreturn5DataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents Pimvendreturn6DataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents Pmvendreturnesc7DataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents AdddtDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents BpsverticalDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents ProdmgrDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents VendNameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents EWOSClassDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents VendPNDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents LongDescDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents QtyavailDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents ValueDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents TurnsDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents InventoryanalystDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents ExecReviewDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents SrnoDataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Friend WithEvents SR120DataGridViewTextBoxColumn As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
```

End Class

**Here is form1.vb - I call form2 via button1 click**

```
Imports DgvFilterPopup
```

Public Class Form1

```
Public filtermanger As DgvFilterManager

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ufm As New Form2

    'showing form2 which has the user control.
    ufm.Owner = Me
    ufm.Show()

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_BindingContextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.BindingContextChanged
    Dim filtermanger As DgvFilterManager
    Dim idx As Integer

    filtermanger = New DgvFilterManager(DataGridView1)
    DataGridView1.GetType.InvokeMember("DoubleBuffered", Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, DataGridView1, New Object() {True})

    With DataGridView1
        .EnableHeadersVisualStyles = False

        For Each col In DataGridView1.Columns

            'format (highlight) editable columns
            Select Case col.datapropertyname
                Case "execsummary", "custliab_1", "reqvendreturn_5", "pimvendreturn_6", "pmvendreturnesc_7", "bpsvertical"
                    idx = col.index
                    .Columns(idx).HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Wheat
                    .Columns(idx).HeaderCell.Style.Font = New Font(DataGridView1.Font, FontStyle.Bold)

                    If col.datapropertyname = "custliab_1" Then
                        .Columns(idx).ToolTipText = "Valid Values (uppercase):" _
                      & vbCrLf & "C : Customer Liable" _
                      & vbCrLf & "V : Vendor Liable(Returnable)" _
                      & vbCrLf & "R : Customer commitment but no Liability" _
                      & vbCrLf & "S : KGP Is Stuck With it As customer Is Not Liable. Cannot Return To vendor, but customer contract requires KGP to keep on hand." _
                      & vbCrLf & "N :  Not Liable (Customer Or Vendor)" _
                      & vbCrLf & "Blank"
                    End If
            End Select
        Next
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dc As DataColumn
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim user As Integer

    'Form3 is the initial form the user see's.  they click one of two buttons.
    user = Form3.user
    For Each col In Me.PIMUserDBDataSet.ewosappendix.Columns
        Select Case user
            Case 1 'EWOS User
                dc = col
                idx = col.ordinal
                Select Case dc.ColumnName
                    Case "execsummary", "custliab_1", "reqvendreturn_5", "pimvendreturn_6", "pmvendreturnesc_7", "bpsvertical"
                        dc.ReadOnly = False
                        DataGridView1.Columns(idx).ReadOnly = False
                    Case Else
                        dc.ReadOnly = True
                        DataGridView1.Columns(idx).ReadOnly = True

                End Select
            Case 2 'Inv Anaylyst
                dc = col
                idx = col.ordinal
                Select Case dc.ColumnName
                    Case "reqvendreturn_5", "pimvendreturn_6", "pmvendreturnesc_7"
                        dc.ReadOnly = False
                        DataGridView1.Columns(idx).ReadOnly = False
                    Case Else
                        dc.ReadOnly = True
                        DataGridView1.Columns(idx).ReadOnly = True
                        'dcdt.ReadOnly = True
                End Select


            Case 3
                dc = col
                idx = col.ordinal
                Select Case dc.ColumnName

                    Case "execsummary", "custliab_1", "reqvendreturn_5", "pimvendreturn_6", "pmvendreturnesc_7", "bpsvertical", " ExecReview", "inventoryanalyst" &
                     ",EWOSClass", "custliab_1", "worker", "prodmgr", "owncode", "executive", "finalown"
                        dc.ReadOnly = False
                        DataGridView1.Columns(idx).ReadOnly = False
                    Case Else
                        dc.ReadOnly = True
                        DataGridView1.Columns(idx).ReadOnly = True
                        'dcdt.ReadOnly = True
                End Select
        End Select

    Next
    Me.EwosappendixTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PIMUserDBDataSet.ewosappendix)
End Sub
```

**Here is Form2.vb.design**

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()>
```

Partial Class Form2
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

```
'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()>
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.UserControl11 = New WindowsApplication6.UserControl1()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'UserControl11
    '
    Me.UserControl11.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(30, 15)
    Me.UserControl11.Name = "UserControl11"
    Me.UserControl11.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(784, 728)
    Me.UserControl11.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'Form2
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(861, 755)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.UserControl11)
    Me.Name = "Form2"
    Me.Text = "Form2"
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)

End Sub

Friend WithEvents UserControl11 As UserControl1
```

End Class

**Here is the Load event for usercontrol1 - which is on Form2. The code between the *  * is where the design error is thrown. See form2 error link above **.

```
Public Class UserControl1
Public Sub UserControl1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim DS As New PIMUserDBDataSet.ewosappendixDataTable
    Dim col As Integer


    DataGridView1.Rows.Add()

    With DS
        For col = 0 To .Columns.Count - 1
            **If CType(Me.ParentForm.Owner, Form1).DataGridView1.Columns(col).ReadOnly = False Then
                ComboBox1.Items.Add(DS.Columns(col).ColumnName)
            End If**
        Next
        ComboBox1.Sorted = True
    End With
```

Comment: What is going on in the `UserControl1` constructor?

Comment: DO u know how to read the stack? What is line 21 of the user control code?

Comment: From the code I posted its in the InitializeComponent sub form2 section.   **Me.Controls.Add(Me.UserControl11)**

Comment: Need more information. DataGridView1 control is in usercontrol1 or Form1 or both ? Does Form 2 has the user control UserControl1 ? Its not clear to me either the design of Form2 or Usercotrol1 has problem ? Please comment the line and take snapshot.

Comment: Also Check the line 21 of UserControl1.Designer.vb. To make it visible select 'show all' toolbar icon in solution explorer.

Comment: Datagridview1 is on form1. –
     
datagridview1 is on Form1 --
Form 2 contains usercontrol1 --
Form 2 design is where the error appears. See screenshot link in 3rd paragraph above.--

I also added a link for form2.designer.vb

Comment: Are you sure the datagridview1 is initialized properly in form 1 before you try to create  form2...?

Comment: by initialization do you mean within the .form1.designer.vb file or within the form1.vb file.  Can you give me an example?

Comment: @Trevor by initialization do you mean within the .form1.designer.vb file or within the form1.vb file. Can you give me an example?

Comment: NOt without seeing your code... but if the grid is not built with columns yet before you call form  2 it will crash

Comment: The reason I ask is you say it is embedded. That raises the question.. is the datagrid initialized before or after form2

Comment: @Trevor , I've added my code.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your control references Form1 through the Owner property of Form2, you need to set that BEFORE the initializer runs.....

Augment Form2's New Method as follows.

```
Public Sub New(myOwner As Form1)

    Owner = myOwner

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

End Sub
```

Then call it this way.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ufm As New Form2(Me)
    ufm.Show()
End Sub
```

And I would change your usercontrol to be safe in the IDE as follows.

```
If me.parentform.owner IsNot Nothing then
    With DS
        For col = 0 To .Columns.Count - 1
            If CType(Me.ParentForm.Owner, Form1).DataGridView1.Columns(col).ReadOnly = False Then
            ComboBox1.Items.Add(DS.Columns(col).ColumnName)
            End If
        Next
        ComboBox1.Sorted = True
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer thanks and u r welcome.

Answer (score 0):

the user control's load event trigged when you open it in your vs design mode, you can add a check condition to do the load when it's not in design time, like:

```
bool designMode = (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime);
```